# can vector<bool> initialized by int

Tags: c++

I want to enum the bool representations of `[0,31]` and store it in `tries` for later uses.

```
static const int N = 5;
vector<bool> tries(N);

for(int i = 0;i < (2<<N); i++){

    //can vector<bool> initialized by int?
    //so I don't have to do bit operation

    for (int t = 0; t < N; ++t)
    {
        tries[t] = i&(1UL<<t);
    }

...
}
```

Comment: Technically vector<bool> isn't *required* to be implemented as a bunch of bits, it's just allowed. So, bitwise operations are really the only *safe* thing to do. If you can be ASSURED that the bools are stored bit by bit, then you *could* do something like (in C++11) `*(int*)tries.data() = int_value_here`. Or in C++98 you could assume that the vector is backed by an array and use `*(int*)(&tries[0]) = int_value_here`.

Comment: @Atash C++11 says "There is no requirement that the data be stored as a contiguous allocation of bool values. A space-optimized representation of bits is recommended instead." and otherwise suggests packing the bits. An implementation that doesn't would quickly break because programs that truly need the bitvector tend to allocate by the megabit. Also, there is no `data` function and no way to access the storage without a custom allocator. Even if you did hack it, the unknown internal element size would screw things up on a little-endian system.

Comment: @Potatoswatter Hence why I said *if*. Also: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data

Comment: @Atash You *can* always be assured they are because literally all implementations work that way. However the knowledge is useless and your suggestions are required not to work. And no, `vector<bool>` does not provide all the members of the primary template.

Comment: @Potatoswatter Double check and - oops. My bad.

Comment: @Atash The `data()` in `libstdc++-v3` [is a dummy function just for debug mode](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=23578) which return `void`. Using this may hard for debug later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::vector< bool >` cannot do this, but `std::bitset` can. Since the size of the vector is constant in your case, you should be using `std::bitset< 5 >`. Simply initialize it with the nonnegative integer value you want.

Note that `bitset` does not provide (or imitate) the Container interface, but it does provide an `operator []` returning a bit-proxy object, like `vector<bool>`.